# Trying to zip a folder using java program but Error - Access Denied

Tags: java

```
    //program to zip a file

    // Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\zipde (Access is denied)
    //at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    //at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    //at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    //at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    //at ZipUtility.pack(ZipUtility.java:26)
    //at ZipUtility.main(ZipUtility.java:19)

    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
    import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
    import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
    import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

    public class ZipUtility {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Path p1 = Paths.get("C:\\zipdemo");
            Path p2 = Paths.get("C:\\zipde");
            pack(p1, p2);


        }

        public static void pack(final Path folder, final Path zipFilePath) throws IOException {
            try (
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFilePath.toFile());
                    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos)
                    ) {
                Files.walkFileTree(folder, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(folder.relativize(file).toString()));
                        Files.copy(file, zos);
                        zos.closeEntry();
                        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                    }

                    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(folder.relativize(dir).toString() + "/"));
                        zos.closeEntry();
                        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where do you get an error? Please provide the stack trace.

Comment: Obviously you are trying to create the file `C:\zipde`, but you do not have write access to the `C:` drive's root directory. Try something like `C:\\temp\\zipdemo.zip` instead.

Comment: Stack trace is provided at the top of the program....

Answer (score 1):

this exception usually occurred in streams, while You are trying to access the directory instead of file. The parameter of the FileOutputStream should be a File/ Path.
For more detail take a look at
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html